# Pagination reloads in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

I have a pagination but it reloads to another page if you select other pages.

I want it not to load to another page but loads the data directly in the same page.

Here is some of my php codes

```
<?php $limit = 15;  
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tblalumni WHERE alum_status = 1 ORDER BY alum_id ASC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query); 
?>
```

here is where it shows the pagination

```
<?php  
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(alum_id) FROM tblalumni WHERE alum_status = 1";  
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);  
    $total_records = $row[0];  
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
    $pagLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    $pagLink .= "<li><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";  
    };  
  echo $pagLink . "</ul></nav>";  
?>
```

here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pagination').pagination({
            items: <?php echo $total_records;?>,
            itemsOnPage: <?php echo $limit;?>,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            currentPage : <?php echo $page;?>,
            hrefTextPrefix : 'confirm_alumni.php?page='
        });
        });
</script>
```

If someone could just suggest ways/ methods. Thank you!